# Can't open more than once jquery dialog

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a jquery dialog, which in  i have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if( window.location.href.indexOf( '#product' ) != -1 ) {
    var productID = window.location.href.split('-');
    showDialog(productID[1]);
}

});

function showDialog(productID)
{
    $( "#dialog-modal_"+productID ).html( "<iframe src='index.php?act=showProduct&amp;id="+productID+"' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>" );
    $( "#dialog-modal_"+productID ).dialog({
    width: 790,
    height: 590,
    modal: true,
    open: function(event, ui)
    {

    }
    });

}
```

it works fine when i open it, but if i close that window and try to re-open it  - it does not responding.

thanks!!

Comment: There is no way to reopen the dialog because it is opened during `$(document).ready` and never any other code to open it again.

Comment: Instead of `window.location.href` use `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a sample of how jQuery UI Dialog code should appear. Remember, you need a way to open the dialog. So create a function that calls `showDialog` on that modal again. A button, or link would work.

**jQuery UI Code**

```
function showDialog(productID)
{
    var container = $('#dialog-modal_'+productID).html('<blah blah>');
    container.dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        width: 790,
        height: 590
    });
    container
        .dialog('option', 'title', 'Your Title')
        .dialog('option', 'buttons', {
            Close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        })
        .dialog('open');
        //do open event work here
}
```

**DOM for a Open Button**

```
<a href="#null" id="open">Open My Modal</a>
```

**jQuery for Open Button**

```
$('a#open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showDialog(<your id>);
});
```